# Access 2010 - Run-time error 3022

Tags: ms-access-2013

I'm trying to add records to an exisiting table called "Topics" (section as of "For Each SelectedTopic In SelectedTopicsCtl.ItemsSelected" in the code below).
When executing the code i always get "Run-time error '3022': The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship.  So it goes wrong at the creation of the Autonumber in the field "ID" (= the only field that is indexed - no duplicates).
When debugging, line "TopicRecord.Update" in the code below is highlighted.
I have read several posts on this topic on this forum and on other forums but still cannot get this to work - i must be overlooking something....

```
Private Sub Copy_Click()

Dim JournalEntrySourceRecord, JournalEntryDestinationRecord, TopicRecord As Recordset
Dim JournalEntryToCopyFromCtl, JournalEntryToCopyToCtl, JournalEntryDateCreatedCtl, SelectedTopicsCtl As Control
Dim Counter, intI As Integer
Dim SelectedTopic, varItm As Variant

Set JournalEntryToCopyFromCtl = Forms![Copy Journal Entry]!JournalEntryToCopyFrom
Set JournalEntryToCopyToCtl = Forms![Copy Journal Entry]!JournalEntryToCopyTo
Set JournalEntryDateCreatedCtl = Forms![Copy Journal Entry]!JournalEntryDateCreated
Set JournalEntrySourceRecord = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from JournalEntries where ID=" & JournalEntryToCopyFromCtl.Value)
Set JournalEntryDestinationRecord = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from JournalEntries where ID=" & JournalEntryToCopyToCtl.Value)
Set SelectedTopicsCtl = Forms![Copy Journal Entry]!TopicsToCopy
Set TopicRecord = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Topics", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)


With JournalEntryDestinationRecord
    .Edit
    .Fields("InitiativeID") = JournalEntrySourceRecord.Fields("InitiativeID")
    .Fields("DateCreated") = JournalEntryDateCreatedCtl.Value
    .Fields("Comment") = JournalEntrySourceRecord.Fields("Comment")
    .Fields("Active") = "True"
    .Fields("InternalOnly") = JournalEntrySourceRecord.Fields("InternalOnly")
    .Fields("Confidential") = JournalEntrySourceRecord.Fields("Confidential")
    .Update
    .Close
End With
JournalEntrySourceRecord.Close
Set JournalEntrySourceRecord = Nothing
Set JournalEntryDestinationRecord = Nothing

For Each SelectedTopic In SelectedTopicsCtl.ItemsSelected
    TopicRecord.AddNew
    For Counter = 3 To SelectedTopicsCtl.ColumnCount - 1
        TopicRecord.Fields(Counter) = SelectedTopicsCtl.Column(Counter, SelectedTopic)
    Next Counter
    TopicRecord.Fields("JournalEntryID") = JournalEntryToCopyToCtl.Value
    TopicRecord.Fields("DateCreated") = JournalEntryDateCreatedCtl.Value
    TopicRecord.Update
Next SelectedTopic
TopicRecord.Close
Set TopicRecord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your Dims won't work as you expect. Use:

```
Dim JournalEntrySourceRecord As Recordset
Dim JournalEntryDestinationRecord As Recordset
Dim TopicRecord As Recordset
```

Second, it looks like you get your ID included here:

```
TopicRecord.Fields(Counter)
```

or *Topic* is a query that includes it somehow. Try to specify the fields specifically and/or debug like this:

```
For Counter = 3 To SelectedTopicsCtl.ColumnCount - 1
    TopicRecord.Fields(Counter).Value = SelectedTopicsCtl.Column(Counter, SelectedTopic)
    Debug.Print Counter, TopicRecord.Fields(Counter).Name
Next Counter
```